# New column to display DD HH:MM:SS from column of total second

Tags: powerbi, seconds

In Power BI, I have a table with a column for Route, and the next column is Seconds. The seconds column displays the amount of seconds for that Route depending on the filters selected, I would like a third column showing  "Days - Hours:Minutes:Seconds" ex:  1 - 07:50:35 instead of 114635.
The seconds column mane in my table is DurationSec in the table [Sudbury Vehicle Line Time].
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7Hgk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Day-h:min:sec = `switch`(true(),
[seconds]/86400>=1,
rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)&" - "
&format(rounddown( ([seconds] - rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)*86400)/3600 ,0),"00")& ":"
&format(rounddown(([seconds] - rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)*86400-rounddown( ([seconds] - rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)*86400)/3600 ,0)*3600)/60,0),"00")&":"
&format([seconds] - rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)*86400-rounddown( ([seconds] - rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)*86400)/3600 ,0)*3600-rounddown(([seconds] - rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)*86400-rounddown( ([seconds] - rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)*86400)/3600 ,0)*3600)/60,0)*60,"00"),

[seconds]/3600>=1,
format(rounddown( ([seconds] - rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)*86400)/3600 ,0),"00")& ":"
&format(rounddown(([seconds] - rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)*86400-rounddown( ([seconds] - rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)*86400)/3600 ,0)*3600)/60,0),"00")&":"
&format([seconds] - rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)*86400-rounddown( ([seconds] - rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)*86400)/3600 ,0)*3600-rounddown(([seconds] - rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)*86400-rounddown( ([seconds] - rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)*86400)/3600 ,0)*3600)/60,0)*60,"00"),

[seconds]/60>=1,
"00:"&format(rounddown(([seconds] - rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)*86400-rounddown( ([seconds] - rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)*86400)/3600 ,0)*3600)/60,0),"00")&":"
&format([seconds] - rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)*86400-rounddown( ([seconds] - rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)*86400)/3600 ,0)*3600-rounddown(([seconds] - rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)*86400-rounddown( ([seconds] - rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)*86400)/3600 ,0)*3600)/60,0)*60,"00"),

"00:00:"&format([seconds] - rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)*86400-rounddown( ([seconds] - rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)*86400)/3600 ,0)*3600-rounddown(([seconds] - rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)*86400-rounddown( ([seconds] - rounddown([seconds]/86400,0)*86400)/3600 ,0)*3600)/60,0)*60,"00")
)

> **`*result in powerbi as below:*`**

[image]

Comment: This returns the correct mathematical result. The one issue is that when I only show the Line and DurationSec columns, I get just one row. Once I add the Day-h:min:sec column, it breaks up the one row into many rows but with the same total time at the end... My DurationSec is set to whole number. Why does the new column break it up?